# Java, combination algorithm with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to implement an algorithm to calculate all combinations of an Array where one character is replaced by '*' without changing the order of the Arrays entries.

For example the following Array with two entries:

{"A", "B"}

Should reproduce this Output:

```
[A, B]
[*, B]
[A, *]
[*, *]
```

My current code is:

```
public class TestCombination {

   public static void combinations(List<String[]> values, String[] attr, String all, int iteration) {
      String[] val = new String[attr.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
         val[i] = attr[i];
      }
      if (iteration < attr.length) {
         val[iteration] = all;
      }

      values.add(val);
      iteration = iteration + 1;

      if (Math.pow(attr.length, 2) != iteration) {
         combinations(values, attr, all, iteration);
      }
   }

   public static void main() {
      String[] values = new String[] {"A", "B"};
      List<String[]> resultValues = new ArrayList<String[]>();
      combinations(resultValues, values, "*", 0);

      for (String[] res : resultValues) {
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(res));
      }
   }

}
```

The Output i get is:

```
[*, B]
[A, *]
[A, B]
[A, B]
```

This is especially because of this not correct code:

```
if (iteration < attr.length) {
    val[iteration] = all;
}
```

I do not have any idea, how the next possible index can be calculated to replace the Array value at that index by '*'.

Can you give me please some hints on that?

Comment: Why is `[B, *]` not an option?

Comment: How's `[*, A]` not changing the order of the array entries?

Comment: After your edit, `[*, B]` is twice. Is it right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, shalid sorry that was a mistake.. i  corrected it.

Comment: So, simplified problem would be generating binary strings of 00, 01, 10, 11, yes?

Comment: He's currently using it

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 in my example i am using recursion. no chance to solve it in a smarter way with recursion as dasblinkenlight did it with bit mask.

Comment: @zennon Depends on what you call smart‌ ! The time complexity of this problem is O(2^n) , you can't do better than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple approach is to use a bit mask of length `n`. Iterate all n-digit binary numbers, and then for each of the `n` positions do the following:

- If position `i` has one, output an asterisk `*`
- If position `i` has zero, output the original value.

This will cover all combinations.

```
String[] a = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};
for (int mask = 0 ; mask != 1<<a.length ; mask++) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != a.length ; i++) {
        if ((mask & 1<<i) != 0) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cKQI7S)

Comment: Thank you. That is an awesome solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to get the current string and one index and one time change the character at that index to `*` and another time call the function without changing the character at that index. Print the result when index reaches end of the string:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        f(new StringBuilder("ABC"),0);
    }

    public static void f(StringBuilder str, int index){
        if (index == str.length()){
            System.out.println(str);
            return;
        }
        f(str, index+1);
        char c = str.charAt(index);
        str.setCharAt(index, '*');
        f(str, index+1);
        str.setCharAt(index, c);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
ABC
AB*
A*C
A**
*BC
*B*
**C
***
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a modification of @dasblinkenlight solution where I'm using recursive function and not mask bit. My solution is in javascript.

```js
var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  len = arr.length,
  pattern = function(startIndex, arr) {
    var newArr = [].concat(arr),
      i;
    newArr[startIndex] = '*';
    console.log(newArr.toString());
    for (i = startIndex + 1; i < len; i++) {
      pattern(i, newArr);
    }
  };
console.log(arr.toString())
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  pattern(i, arr);
}
```